# How do I know if a JS code fired using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-tag-manager

We're using Google Tag Manager as a tag management solution. We use it to fire various codes such as Facebook pixels and such. Without using any extension/add-on and without searching for the script in the code manually - how can I tell if a specific script runs directly from the code or by GTM? Is there any metadata that GTM applies to the script? 
When looking in the devTools/network I see that the script (e.g. facebook.js) runs but we're looking for a "flag" that implies it runs by GTM.
I hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome DevTools Network tab, you can either hover over the "Initiator" column entry for the script or select the row for the script and look at the "Initiator" tab.  If you see gtm.js?is=GTM-XXXXXXXX in the call stack, then GTM initiated the request.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: It seems it works sometimes. We have some scripts that show the back JS as the initiator and not GTM. We'll look into it further.